# PushKit notifications not received after quitting airplane mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, pushkit

I am implementing a VoIP app on IOS. I have implemented PushKit on my app and everything works fine.
When my device has no network (airplane mode for instance) I don't receive any push notifications (which is okay since i'm not connected to any server).
But when my device is back in the network (quit airplane mode) I still don't receive the push...
On old API with remote and local notifications it was possible so why not with PushKit ?

Thanks in advance for the help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it !
I've put a Ttl of 60s to the push which was too short for apple so the push wasn't resend to my device.
Augmenting the ttl solved my issue !
Hope it can help someone with the same issue !

Comment: Good contribution.

Comment: Can you post a link to the reference (or any other doc)?